# Getting a BAD_EXC_ERROR and have pinpointed it to this bit of code

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am currently working on an iPad application and have a piece of code that's causing BAD_EXC_Calls. I am trying to create the mask layer for these pages however it keeps causing errors when I run my application eventually causing it to crash. Could somebody please review this code and see where I might be messing it up? The code itself works in the sense that the layer shows up, it allows everything to show up on the webview but switching between tabs that have this layer causes this bad_Exc_call. Also it doesn't display the webview when actually tested on the iPad. The code itself works but it seems to be random when it does.

```
if ([self.view viewWithTag:2] != nil && !maskLayer)
{
    maskLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];

    CGColorRef outerColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.0].CGColor;
    CGColorRef midColor   = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.5].CGColor;
    CGColorRef innerColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;

    maskLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)CFBridgingRelease(outerColor),
                        (id)CFBridgingRelease(midColor),
                        (id)CFBridgingRelease(innerColor),
                        (id)CFBridgingRelease(innerColor),
                        (id)CFBridgingRelease(midColor),
                        (id)CFBridgingRelease(outerColor), nil];
    maskLayer.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.1],
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.15],
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.85],
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.9],
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];

    maskLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                  self.productsWebView.frame.size.width,
                                  self.productsWebView.frame.size.height);

    maskLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
    self.productsWebView.layer.mask = maskLayer;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wondering: What does the static analyser think of your code?

Look at the lifetimes of these objects: ColorWithWhite produces auto-released objects. The CGColor property returns objects bound to the life time of the UIColor object, so they disappear as well when ColorWithWhite's autoreleasepool disappears. So effectively, CGColor is released (not yet, but soon).

CFBridgingRelease transfers ownership to ARC and tells ARC "you need to release this". Which is wrong, because the CGColorRef objects are already autoreleased. That causes the crash.

Comment: The static analyser doesn't seem to be thinking much of it. And I see,  so I should not be using CFBridgingRelease because of the releasing nature it has?